# Scala: Play Framework 2 ignores httpOnly flag in application.conf

Tags: javascript, html, scala, playframework-2.1, cookie-httponly

I want to use i18n in my Play-Application (Play 2.1, Scala). The chosen language is stored in the `PLAY_LANG-Cookie`, but unfortunately this cookie is `httpOnly`. That means I can't read its value in my JavaScript files.

I tried changing the `httpOnly-Value` in the `application.conf`, but it didn't work.

```
application.session.httpOnly=false
```

I haven't found anything on this yet, so I'd really appreciate some help!

Answer (score 1):

you can pass it to your scala template in the samy way we do with session

```
@(implicit session:play.api.mvc.Session, lang:play.api.i18n.Lang)
```

now you can pass `@lang.code` to the javscript. does the same functianlity but by diffrent approach.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration key has been renamed to session.httpOnly. I didn't find anything about this from recent documentation though. So in you `application.conf`:

> session.httpOnly=false